# ExtJS 4.1.1: Evaluating a field in a grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I'm struggling with a ExtJS 4.1.1 `grid` that has editable cells ([CellEditing plugin](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing)).

A person should be able to type a mathematic formula into the cell and it should generate the result into the field's value. For example: If a user types `(320*10)/4` the return should be `800`. Or similar if the user types `(320m*10cm)/4` the function should strip the non-mathematical characters from the formula and then calculate it.

I was looking to replace (or match) with a RegExp, but I cannot seem to get it to work. It keeps returning NaN and when I do `console.log(e.value);` it returns only the `originalValue` and not the `value` that I need.

I don't have much code to attach:

```
onGridValidateEdit : function(editor,e,opts) {
    var str = e.value.toString();
    console.log(str);
    var strCalc = str.match(/0-9+-*\/()/g);
    console.log(strCalc);
    var numCalc = Number(eval(strCalc));
    console.log(numCalc);
    return numCalc;
},
```

Which returns: `str=321` `strCalc=null` `numCalc=0` when I type `321*2`.

Any help appreciated,

GR.

---

### Update:

Based on [input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11436041/1341063) by Paul Schroeder, I created this:

```
onGridValidateEdit : function(editor,e,opts) {
    var str = e.record.get(e.field).toString();
    var strCalc = str.replace(/[^0-9+*-/()]/g, "");
    var numCalc = Number(eval(strCalc));
    console.log(typeof numCalc);
    console.log(numCalc);
    return numCalc;
},
```

Which calculates the number, but I am unable to print it back to the grid itself. It shows up as "NaN" even though in console it shows `typeof=number` and `value=800`.

---

### Final code:

Here's the final code that worked:

```
onGridValidateEdit : function(editor,e,opts) {
    var fldName = e.field;
    var str = e.record.get(fldName).toString();
    var strCalc = str.replace(/[^0-9+*-/()]/g, "");
    var numCalc = Number(eval(strCalc));
    e.record.set(fldName,numCalc);
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break this code down.

```
onGridValidateEdit : function(editor,e,opts) {
    var str = e.value.toString();
```

What listener is this code being used in?  This is very important for us to know, here's how I set up my listeners in the plugin:

```
listeners: {
            edit: function(editor, e){
                var record = e.record;
                var str = record.get("your data_index of the value");
            }
        }
```

Setting it up this way works for me, So lets move on to:

```
   var strCalc = str.match(/0-9+-*\/()/g);
    console.log(strCalc);
```

at which point strCalc=null, this is also correct. str.match returns null because your regex does not match anything in the string.  What I think you want to do instead is this:

```
var strCalc = str.replace(/[^0-9+*-]/g, "");
console.log(strCalc);
```

This changes it to replace all characters in the string that aren't your equation operators and numbers.  After that I think it should work for whole numbers.  I think that you may actually want decimal numbers too, but I can't think of the regex for that off the top of my head (the . needs to be escaped somehow), but it should be simple enough to find in a google search.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear what listener this code was used in:  this.control({'#raGrid' : {validateedit: this.onGridValidateEdit}});

Comment: I've used some of your suggestions, I see it returning the correct value in log and that it's a number, but how do I return it to the grid itself? I have tried using return and setting e.value, but no luck